# In Salesforce1 app unable to get recordId from currentPageReference wire adapter passed from previous page

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforce1-app, navigation, lightningnavigation, navigationmixin.navigate

I am working on Salesforce LWC in Salesforce1 mobile app. Lwc core functionality @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef; is throwing following error on console and i am unable to get recordId from previous page.

I am doing this to get recordId.

```
@wire(CurrentPageReference) getPageRef(pageRef){

    this.recordId = pageRef.state.c__rid;

}
```

passing recordId from previous page like this:

```
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({

      type: "standard__navItemPage",

      attributes: {

        apiName: "Line_Item_Detail_Page",

      },

      state: {c__rid: this.id}

    });
```

---

```
Error: [LWC error]: Invalid event type "WireContextEvent" dispatched in 
element <c-lineitemdetail-header-component>. Event name must 1) Start with a 
lowercase letter 2) Contain only lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores

<c-lineitemdetail-header-component>
at Object.logError (aura_proddebug.js:4268)

at ConstructionEstimation.dispatchEvent (aura_proddebug.js:7622)

at ConstructionEstimation.wrappedMethod [as dispatchEvent] 
(aura_proddebug.js:12985)

at WireEventTarget.dispatchEvent (aura_proddebug.js:9501)

at d.get (contextService.js:2)

at eval (contextService.js:2)

at E (contextService.js:2)

at Object.t.getContextValue (contextService.js:2)

at c.getCurrentPageReference (pageService.js:2)

at eval (navigation.js:2)
```

On desktop and mobile via chrome browser it is working fine even though there is this error in console. But in Salesforce1 mobile App it is not working due to unable to get recordId from pageRef. I tried to find way to debug Salesforce mobile app but i could not find any way to debug mobile app.

Comment: Did you get any update on this, I'm also experiencing the same issue

Comment: Yes I got it's solution. It is here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2HjSTyRgj4&list=PLrC_ei2_Pv0HYjsdObH1mJ6nRh4LGVn8X